# creating a link to a network file on a wiki page

Tags: wiki

I am trying to link a specific document sitting on a server in a wiki page.

Say the server is \myserver
and the file is at \myserver\share\myfolder\myfile.txt

How do I do that?
tried the following, and none seem to work:

```
[file://myserver\share\myfolder\myfile.txt LinkHere]
[file:///myserver\share\myfolder\myfile.txt LinkHere]
[file:////myserver\share\myfolder\myfile.txt LinkHere]
[file://\\myserver\share\myfolder\myfile.txt LinkHere]
[file:////myserver/share/myfolder/myfile.txt LinkHere]
[file://myserver//share//myfolder//myfile.txt LinkHere]
```

Seems annoying, since my web browser opens such a link easily, and linking to an http page works fine:

```
[http://www.somesite.com/index.html AnotherLinkHere]
```

So, Ho do I do that?

Comment: Security makes this difficult to use as simply as you wish. With greater specificity we may be able help. What is your Wiki engine? What browsers do you need to support. I've had some success with Wiki engines that include a backing Internet Information Server (IIS). Generally, I share a folder via the backing web server for use in storing files that I want to stage for linking to Wiki pages. It’s a non-trivial setup but it works. I also use it to stage third-party or generated HTML documentation, etc.

Answer (score -2):

Use a mapped network drive to access the folder via Firefox.  This means mapping myserver as the Q: drive in the example below.

```
    file:///Q:/share/myfolder/myfile.txt
```